# How to extend Keychain in OSX or iOS?

Tags: ios, keychain

Can I store something else beside passwords in Keychain, for example biometrics?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the Keychain was made to securely store user data, besides small secure notes. Maybe it is better to take the following approach, which allows the user to easily transfer his data between multiple computers, securely.

1. Ask the user for a password (once).
2. Store the data encrypted with that password on the file system (using OpenSSL or an other library)
3. Store the **password** with the filename in the Keychain
4. When the user opens the file, ask the Keychain for the password of the file. Unless the user has manually blocked your application access to that password, the Keychain will NOT present the user with a dialog for the password. It will just give you the password.